# jquery version of array.contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can jQuery test an array for the presence of an object (either as part of the core functionality or via an avaible plugin)?

Also, I'm looking for something like `array.remove`, which would remove a given object from an array. Can jQuery handle this for me?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[jQuery.inArray](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray) returns the first index that matches the item you searched for or -1 if it is not found:

```
if($.inArray(valueToMatch, theArray) > -1) alert("it's in there");
```

You shouldn't need an array.remove.  Use splice:

```
theArray.splice(startRemovingAtThisIndex, numberOfItemsToRemove);
```

Or, you can perform a "remove" using the [jQuery.grep](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep) util:

```
var valueToRemove = 'someval';
theArray = $.grep(theArray, function(val) { return val != valueToRemove; });
```

Comment: Thanks Prestaul. Thing is, I don't know the index of the object I need to remove, so I think I still need array.remove.

Comment: oh, cool. Right there in the docs under "utilities". "RTFM" would have been an acceptalbe answer:) thanks for pointing me there though. I think jquery.grep may give me the remove functionality I need.

Comment: @morgancodes, it will indeed!  I was adding that to my answer as you were commenting.

Comment: also: theArray.splice($.inArray(value, theArray), 1);

Comment: @thenduks, I avoided that because it only works if your array contents are all unique.  It only removes the first match.

Comment: BTW: "theArray.splice($.inArray(value, theArray), 1);" only works if the item is in the list.

Answer (score 3):

If your list contains a list of elements, then you can use [jQuery.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or [jQuery.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do your "array.remove".   (Answer added because of the high google score of your original question).

Comment: "(Answer added because of the high google score of your original question)" ??!! - What about "Answer added because I want to help" ??

Comment: I don't think I'm answering the original question, but it's information that might be useful to somebody whose searches land here.

Answer (score 0):

I found way to remove object:

```
foot = { bar : 'test'};
delete foot[bar];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not jQuery, but in one line you can add a handy 'contains' method to arrays. I find this helps with readability (especially for python folk).

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(a){ return this.indexOf(a) != -1 }
```

example usage

```
 > var a = [1,2,3]
 > a.contains(1)
true
 > a.contains(4)
false
```

Similarly for remove

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(a){if (this.contains(a)){ this.splice(this.indexOf(a),1)}; return this}

> var a = [1,2,3]
> a.remove(2)
[1,3]
```

Or, if you want it to return the thing removed rather than the altered array, then

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(a){if (this.contains(a)){ return this.splice(this.indexOf(a),1)}}

> var a = [1,2,3]
> a.remove(2)
[2]
> a
[1,3]
```