# Clean way to remove element from javascript array (with jQuery, coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

There are many questions about this, not least:
  [jQuery version of array contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450717/jquery-version-of-array-contains), [a solution with the splice method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231453/in-javascript-how-do-i-remove-an-element-from-an-array-of-objects) and many more. However, they all seem complicated and annoying.

With the combined powers of javascript, jQuery and coffeescript, what is the very cleanest way to remove an element from a javascript array? We don't know the index in advance. In code:

```
a = [4,8,2,3]
a.remove(8)     # a is now [4,2,3]
```

Failing a good built-in method, what is a clean way of extending javascript arrays to support such a method? If it helps, I'm really using arrays as sets. Solutions will ideally work nicely in coffeescript with jQuery support. Also, I couldn't care less about speed, but instead prioritize clear, simple code.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

CoffeeScript:

```
Array::remove = (e) -> @[t..t] = [] if (t = @indexOf(e)) > -1
```

Which simply splices out the element at position `t`, the index where `e` was found (if it was actually found `t > -1`). Coffeescript translates this to:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(e) {
    var t, _ref;
    if ((t = this.indexOf(e)) > -1) {
        return ([].splice.apply(this, [t, t - t + 1].concat(_ref = [])), _ref);
    }
};
```

And if you want to remove all matching elements, and return a new array, using CoffeeScript and jQuery:

```
Array::remove = (v) -> $.grep @,(e)->e!=v
```

which translates into:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(v) {
    return $.grep(this, function(e) {
        return e !== v;
    });
};
```

Or doing the same without jQuery's grep:

```
Array::filterOutValue = (v) -> x for x in @ when x!=v
```

which translates to:

```
Array.prototype.filterOutValue = function(v) {
    var x, _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = this.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        x = this[_i];
        if (x !== v) {
            _results.push(x);
        }
    }
    return _results;
};
```

Comment: Clearly you have been using CoffeeScript for much longer than I; +1 for what looks to be very idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks @Amir for a great, idiomatic answer. The other answers are helpful, too; I like this one because it uses the available tools to make things simpler. One minor change: I'll probably call it `Array::removing`, as in `smaller_array = larger_array.removing(something)`, so it's clear that it returns a new array.

Comment: You mean for the second one? I would personally call it `filterOutValue`, but to each his own. Naming variables and functions is the hardest part of programming :)

Comment: God damn coffeescript is beautiful. I believe you can get rid of the @.indexOf and just do @indexOf (no dot).

Comment: Get rid of the unnecessary `concat`: `Array::remove = (v) -> @splice i, 1 if i = @indexOf(v) > -1`

Comment: Modern JS engines also have `filter`: `a = a.filter (v) -> v not 5`

Comment: If one doesn't use `filter`, then replacing `if` with `while` will remove all appearances, i.e. `Array::remove = (v) -> @splice i, 1 while (i = @indexOf(v)) > -1` BTW, @Ricardo Tomasi, you do need brackets in the condition, see http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try:Array%3A%3Aremove%20%3D%20(v)%20-%3E%20%40splice%20i%2C%201%20while%20(i%20%3D%20%40indexOf(v))%20%3E%20-1%0A%0Aa%20%3D%20new%20Array()%0Aa.push%201%0Aa.push%202%0Aa.push%203%0Aa.push%202%0A%0Aa.remove%202%0A%0Aalert%20a

Comment: Thanks to this `$.grep @,(e)->e!=v` I will never think about using CoffeeScript, ever again. Readability equals zero.

Answer (score 28):

Using vanilla Javascript:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(elem) {
    var match = -1;

    while( (match = this.indexOf(elem)) > -1 ) {
        this.splice(match, 1);
    }
};

var a = [4, 8, 2, 3];

a.remove(8);
```

Only jQuery:

```
jQuery.removeFromArray = function(value, arr) {
    return jQuery.grep(arr, function(elem, index) {
        return elem !== value;
    });
};

var a = [4, 8, 2, 3];

a = jQuery.removeFromArray(8, a);
```

Comment: Although I of course should benchmark, I would suspect this would be slower due to `indexOf` being O(n), giving you total complexity O(n * m + n) for m the number of matches. My answer makes a single pass, giving O(n) complexity.

Comment: @Domenic: of course. `.index()` is not as fast, but it's fair enough and less code. If I was after performance, I'd using a `while()` loop anyway: see http://jsperf.com/benchmark-for-domenic

Comment: Haha, your jsPerf has uncovered a difference between Chrome and Firefox 4b10, nice! The `for` version ran much faster in my Firefox than it apparently did in your Chrome. Cool!

Comment: @Domenic: indeed pretty wierd.

Answer (score 14):

This is really easy with jQuery:

```
var index = $.inArray("value", myArray);
if(index != -1)
{
  myArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Notes:

`splice` returns the elements that were removed, so don't do `myArray = myArray.splice()`.  `myArray.splice(index,1)` means "remove the array element at index `'index'` from the array".

`$.inArray` returns the index in the array of the value you're looking for, or -1 if the value isn't in the array.

Comment: almost as easy as with vanilla JS

Comment: This appears to remove only a single matching entry. An array can contain multiple entries of the same value.

Comment: The question asks: "what is the very cleanest way to remove **an** element from a javascript array?"

Answer (score 9):

This seems pretty clean and understandable; unlike other answers, it takes into account the possibility of an element showing up more than once.

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ) {
        if (this[i] === value) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
           ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

In CoffeeScript:

```
Array::remove = (value) ->
    i = 0
    while i < @length
        if @[i] == value
            @splice i, 1
        else
            ++i
    return @
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are also using CoffeeScript creator's [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#) library, here's a one-liner that will work nicely:

```
a = _(a).reject (v)-> v is e
```

or in js:

```
a = _(a).reject(function(v) { return v == e; });
```

Answer (score 4):

Although you are asking for a clean approach using Coffeescript or jQuery, I find the cleanest approach is using the vanilla javascript method [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
array.filter(function (item) { return item !== match });
```

It looks cleaner in coffeescript but this translates to the exact same javascript, so I only consider it a visual difference, and not an advanced feature of coffeescript:

```
array.filter (item) -> item isnt match
```

Filter is not supported in legacy browsers, but Mozilla provides a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) that adheres to the ECMA standard. I think this is a perfectly safe approach because you are only bringing old browsers to modern standards, and you are not inventing any new functionality in your polyfill.

Sorry if you were specifically looking for a jQuery or Coffeescript only method, but I think you were mainly asking for a library method because you were unaware of a clean javascript only method.

There you have it, no libraries needed!

Comment: I like this approach and reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a slight change to [Amir's awesome solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825812/clean-way-to-remove-element-from-javascript-array-with-jquery-coffeescript/4826179#4826179):

```
Array::remove = (e) -> @splice(t,1)[0] if (t = @indexOf(e)) > -1
```

which returns the element iff the list has it, so you can do something like:

```
do_something 100 if a.remove(100)
```

The remove coffee script translates to this javascript:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(e) {
  var t, _ref;
  if ((t = this.indexOf(e)) > -1) {
    return ([].splice.apply(this, [t, t - t + 1].concat(_ref = [])), _ref);
  }};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just try jQuery's grep utility:

```
a = [4,8,2,3]
$.grep(a,function(v){return v!=8;})
```

There may be a performance issue here, as you're technically causing the variable to reference a *new* array; you're not really modifying the original one. Assuming the original isn't referenced somewhere else, the garbage collector should take or this pretty quickly. This has never been an issue for me, but others might know better. Cheers!