# Filter with CoffeeScript list comprehensions

Tags: list-comprehension, coffeescript

The CoffeeScript docs state that list comprehensions should be able to do the select/filter operations:

> They should be able to handle most
>   places where you otherwise would use a
>   loop, each/forEach, map, or
>   select/filter.

You'd imagine you could do something in one line like `result = item for item in list if item % 2 == 0`
However the closest I can come is

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
result = []
for item in list
  if item % 2 == 0 then result.push item
```

Whats the most concise way to filter a list in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
result = (item for item in list when item % 2 == 0)
```

**edit** : added `result =`

Comment: Put that in a function, otherwise, it does nothing. Type it into "Try Coffeescript" in http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/ and look at the javascript output.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are trying to squeeze every ounce of performance out, I would create a filter function like this:

```
filter = (list, func) -> x for x in list when func(x)
```

or if you want to add it to the prototype of every array:

```
Array::filter = (func) -> x for x in @ when func(x)
```

and then write: (respectively)

```
result = filter mylist, (x) -> x % 2 == 0
```

or

```
result = mylist.filter (x) -> x % 2 == 0
```

For reference, this is the javascript that gets generated:

```
var filter, result;
filter = function(list, func) {
    var x, _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = list.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        x = list[_i];
        if (func(x)) {
            _results.push(x);
        }
    }
    return _results;
};
Array.prototype.filter = function(func) {
    var x, _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = this.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        x = this[_i];
        if (func(x)) {
            _results.push(x);
        }
    }
    return _results;
};
result = filter(mylist, function(x) {
    return x % 2 === 0;
});
result = mylist.filter(function(x) {
    return x % 2 === 0;
});
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825812/clean-way-to-remove-element-from-javascript-array-with-jquery-coffeescript)

Comment: Its definitely a matter of personal preference as they both get the job done - but taking python as an example, list comprehensions are generally preferred over functional programming functions when possible since they are considered more readable.

Comment: wat. Array already has this exact function… (just maybe more efficient)