# Remove a value from an array in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have an array:

```coffee
array = [..., "Hello", "World", "Again", ...]
```

How could I check if "World" is in the array?
Then remove it if it exists?
And have a reference to "World"?

Sometimes maybe I wanna match a word with a regexp and in that case I won't know the exact string so I need to have a reference to the matched String. But in this case I know for sure it's "World" which makes it simpler.

Thanks for the suggestions. I found a cool way to do it:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825812/clean-way-to-remove-element-from-javascript-array-with-jquery-coffeescript

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[`array.indexOf("World")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) will get the index of `"World"` or `-1` if it doesn't exist. [`array.splice(indexOfWorld, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will remove `"World"` from the array.

Comment: The solutions below offer better coffeescript syntax. But if you only have one element to remove from the array, this workflow has better performance as it won't traverse the whole array looking for more elements with the same value.

Comment: @ErikJ: “Better” CoffeeScript syntax?

Comment: @ryanh: You're right, better isn't the right word, but the others offered alternatives that take advantage of CoffeeScript-specific features

Answer (score 73):

`filter()` is also an option:

```
arr = [..., "Hello", "World", "Again", ...]

newArr = arr.filter (word) -> word isnt "World"
```

Comment: Important difference: this solution is not destructive, i.e. `arr` will stay the same (which is usually good functional practice). Compare with accepted answer, which is destructive.

Comment: In the question, he is asking to have a reference to "World"

Comment: Note that (awkwardly enough) this is space-sensitive; `arr.filter(word) -> word isn't "Word"` generates a JavaScript error.

Comment: @ashes999 it's not that awkward actually. what you write is syntactically wrong. `arr.filter (word) -> word isn't "Word"` means that "execute the filter function with a `(word) -> word isn't "Word"` function parameter"

Answer (score 17):

For this is such a natural need, I often prototype my arrays with an `remove(args...)` method.

My suggestion is to write this somewhere:

```
Array.prototype.remove = (args...) ->
  output = []
  for arg in args
    index = @indexOf arg
    output.push @splice(index, 1) if index isnt -1
  output = output[0] if args.length is 1
  output
```

And use like this anywhere:

```
array = [..., "Hello", "World", "Again", ...]
ref = array.remove("World")
alert array # [..., "Hello", "Again",  ...]
alert ref   # "World"
```

This way you can also remove multiple items at the same time:

```
array = [..., "Hello", "World", "Again", ...]
ref = array.remove("Hello", "Again")
alert array # [..., "World",  ...]
alert ref   # ["Hello", "Again"]
```

Comment: `splice` returns an array, so it should probably be `@splice(index,1)[0]`

Comment: I'd use `?=` to avoid overriding it if it has already been defiend.

Answer (score 15):

Checking if "World" is in array:

```
"World" in array
```

Removing if exists

```
array = (x for x in array when x != 'World')
```

or

```
array = array.filter (e) -> e != 'World'
```

Keeping reference (that's the shortest I've found - !.push is always false since .push > 0)

```
refs = []
array = array.filter (e) -> e != 'World' || !refs.push e
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
filter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

#Remove "b" and "d" from the array in one go
filter.splice(index, 1) for index, value of filter when value in ["b", "d"]
```

Comment: This does not work as expected when deleting a second last item from the array. See http://jsfiddle.net/8v25L/

Answer (score 2):

A combination of a few answers:

```
Array::remove = (obj) ->
  @filter (el) -> el isnt obj
```

Answer (score 2):

`_.without()` function from the [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#without) library is a good and clean option in case you want to get a new array :

```
_.without([1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4], 0, 1)
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript + jQuery:
remove one, not all

```
arrayRemoveItemByValue = (arr,value) ->
  r=$.inArray(value, arr)
  unless r==-1
    arr.splice(r,1)
  # return
  arr

console.log arrayRemoveItemByValue(['2','1','3'],'3')
```